# Get the current session with spring-session

Tags: spring-session

Here's my question: I'm writing a platform which I will be giving to the customers to implement their projects with. So in my platform I have created a `SessionService` in which I have methods like `getCurrentSession`, `getAttribute`, `setAttribute`, etc. Before spring-session my `getCurrentMethod` looked like this:

`@Override
    public HttpSession getCurrentSession() {
        if (this.session == null) {
            final ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
            return attr.getRequest().getSession(true); // true == allow create
        }
        return this.session;
    }`

which worked perfectly fine, although it looks ugly and have no backing like redis. Now I want to migrate to `spring-session` and I was hoping to use the `SessionRepository` to find the current session of the user, however I can only see a `getSession(String id)` in there. I believe the id is stored in the cookie, so to use it I will probably have to pass the `HttpServletRequest` object from my controllers, to my facades, to the service layer which is very near the db layer. This looks like a very bad idea to me, so my question would be: is there any way to get the currentSession near the db layer? One way I would think is to write an interceptor that will be invoked the controllers, which will set the current session in the repository, or the service maybe? I'm just not sure this is the right way to go.

Comment: You don't generally need a session service. Spring handles it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Obtaining the Session Id from Service Layer**

You can use the `RequestContextHolder` to retrieve the session id, set attributes, and remove attributes.

The `RequestContextHolder` is typically setup using `RequestContextListener` or `RequestContextFilter`. Spring Session does NOT work with `RequestContextListener` because there is no way for Spring Session to wrap the request before the `RequestContextListener` is invoked.

Unfortunately, this means for Spring Boot applications, `RequestContextHolder` does not work out of the box. To work around it you can create a `RequestContextFilter` Bean. See [spring-boot/gh-2637](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2637) for updates on this issue.

**Should I be putting this in session?**

Just because it is easy to put a lot of objects in session and it is stored in Redis does not mean it is the right thing to do.

Keep in mind that the entire session is retrieved on every request. So while Redis is fast, this can have a significant impact if there are lots of objects in session. Obviously the implementation can be optimized for your situation, but I think the concept of session generally holds this property.

A general rule of thumb is, "Do I need this object for over 95% of my requests?"  (read this as almost all of my requests). If so, it may be a candidate for session. In most cases, the object should be security related if it fits this criteria.

**Should I access session id from ThreadLocal in the service layer?**

This is certainly open for debate as code is as much of an art as it is a science.

However, I'd argue that you should not be obtaining the session id from thread locale variables throughout your architecture. Doing this feels a bit like obtaining a "Person id" and obtaining the current "Person id" from the HttpServletRequest in a ThreadLocale. Instead, values should be obtained from the controller and passed into your service layer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not need changing. It will return the Spring Session session object.

Though it is generally better to inject the `HttpSession` from the controller, or use session-scoped beans and `@SessionAttribute` than to have such a session service in the first place.